# series problem feedback needed

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

this is a example from my lecture notes and while studying i cannot understand how the final answer is found. the particular place where i am confused i have circled. shouldn't it be -1/n(n+1) ?

[image]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: 3rd binomial and "$-- = +$, so lecture notes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$
\displaystyle\frac1{n(n+1)}.
$

Comment: i have fixed that error is it correct now?

Comment: @johnnitro Yes, but with the `+` sign, as $n^2-(n+1)(n-1)=1$.